# Creating and using segue to launch storyboard view via didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uistoryboard

I have a table view with cells created with:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"GalleryCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }
        NSMutableArray *gallery = [gallerys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        cell.textLabel.text = [gallery objectAtIndex:1];

        return cell;

}
```

What I need to be able to do is within the didSelectRowAtIndexPath, fire a segue to launch another view, this will also send some information across using the prepareForSegue method.

This issue is I am not sure how to go about creating the segue to be used in this instance as within the storyboard I have nothing to attach it to (no buttons etc) and the cells are created within the code, is it possible to also create the segue in the code? Or is there another method to this?

Comment: So, your storyboard has only the `UIViewControllers` or you don't use a storyboard at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, you can attach it to your table view controller, it is not necessary to attach it to a button. Just go to the storyboard and do the following:

1. Right click on the VC that you would like to push.
2. Under Presenting Segues in the menu click and hold 'push' and drag it to your table view controller.
3. Choose manual when the dialog shows above your table view controller.
4. Select the segue after it appears and go to its attribute inspector.
5. Choose a name for the segue.
6. Call performSegue

Comment: Thank you, this answer explained how to set the segue up which was the issue

Comment: I am getting this error: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<KCMediaViewController: 0xa64b7a0>) has no segue with identifier 'mediatogallery''

Comment: It is pretty clear what the exception is about, something is wrong with the way the segue is setup from your KCMediaViewController to your gallery, either it is not there or its identifier is different. Did you double-check that the segue identifier you specified in the storyboard is the same you attempt to use in code - 'mediatogallery'?

Answer (score 0):

Push your view controller

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueID" sender:self];
```

You can send the information as below

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"yourSegueID"]) {

        YourViewController *yourVC = segue.destinationViewController;

        yourVC.information = myInformation;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply drag a segue from your table to destination Controller and give a name for that.
And in didSelectRowAtIndexPath call

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" sender:self];
```

then following method will get called

```
  -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {

    // here you can pass any value to new ViewController;
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MySegue"]) {
    YourNewViewController *VC = segue.destinationViewController;

    VC.data = yourData;
}
    }
```